# Php causes margin in top of my wordpress website

Tags: php, css, wordpress, margin

i'm working on a website :

http://mtcdistrup.cluster003.ovh.net/

This site is under wordpress, and everytimes I use a Php code, it does marge it like 20px, as u cat see, for the cart icon I used a span and put some php in it, the span is marged at top. On another page I use several times and there is more margin, like one in the header and one more above the cart icon, I don't really know where does it come from.

I saw a lot of forums topics about it, but nothing changed it, it seems like it put almost the same margin as the admin bar every time I use php.

I saw some topic saying " it's because u are logged " so i went on a browser that i never logged onto my WordPress ac on, and there is still the margin for this. I really don't know where does it come from. If u guys have any idea, it would save my life.

Thanks in advance, cheers.

Comment: PHP by itself doesn't add margins. In cases like this, what you can do is look at the page using your browser's inspect tools and start removing things until the problem goes away. Then the last thing you removed is the cause of the problem.

Comment: the thing in the header on the right like a bag with an E on is the header? I should have tell it, nevermind

Answer (score 1):

This is not due to php code.. margin from top is causing due to tag difference. Add this css code into your stylesheet..

```
.header-bottom .content-right a, .header-bottom .content-right span {
    float: left;
}
.header-bottom .content-right {
    float: right !important;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 126px;
}
```

I hope it will fix your problem

Comment: thanks a lot, u are right, i just used it and it worked, u are a boss. Thanks for ur time, really thanks again.
I'm good at seo/marketing/photoshop/illustrator and self improvement. If there is anything in it i can help u with, it would be a pleasure to me.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS is what adds top margin to your shopping cart button.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    header .header-bottom [class^="icon-"] {
        margin-top: 28px;
    }
}
```

Comment: when i remove it, it also removes the margin of the " login " and " newsletter thing " :/

Comment: in fact, this margin appears only after i put the php in the " cart's" span, if i remove the php from there, then the margin goes